# RavenDB 2.0: Indexing with SpatialGenerate eats up all memory

Tags: c#, nosql, ravendb, spatial, spatial-index

Problem: In the code presented I am trying to index ~26000 geo-fences (polygons). I have tried many combinations of 1)inserting the data and 2)indexing the data that some are not presented in the code for brevity. I have imported all the data with pre-built index; importing the data and then making the index and making the index and importing the data partially with waiting for non-stale index. In all cases it eats up all the memory and fails (by fail I mean I wait for 30 minutes for completing the indexing process). One interesting observation happened in partial inserts with pre-built index: It always starts to eat up all memory around ~1790 entries.

Environment: I have tested this on 2 machines: 1) 4 GB Ram, Dual Core 2.56 CUP 2) 12 GB Ram, i7 CPU. I used Visual Studio 2012 (which should not be important) targeted .NET 4.0 with RavenDB build 2230. The only external library used here (other than RavenDB client libraries) was NetTopologySuite (NuGet).

Side Note and Background: I am doing my spatial calculations using 2 in-memory data structures: a KD-Tree and an R-Tree with static data (no insert/delete/update). Now a new step added to my project which needs to update/insert some data twice a day; because of that I searched for a replacement to remove the burden of housekeeping of this part and I came up with SQLite R-Tree module. It is fast enough (using some parallel programming+it is a mostly read-only database). So far RavenDB is not much of a choice (strategic decisions; etc) but I liked to play with it and it was disappointing. To be precise I love RavenDB 960 and I really am angry with RavenDB 2230.

I have used the in-memory trees and tested SQLite with ~3,000,000 polygons (again to be precise "bounding boxes") and failed to use RavenDB for ~26,000 polygons. I really hope that I am doing something badly wrong.

The code:

```
namespace MyApp
{
    static partial class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Initialization();
            InitializeIndexes();

            // MODE 1:
            // OneTimeImport(-1, 1024, true);

            // MODE 2:
            // OneTimeImport(-1, 1024, false);

            // MODE 3:
            // PartialImport(64); and PartialImport(32); and PartialImport(16);
        }

        static void PartialImport(int len)
        {
            bool finished = false;
            int index = 0;

            // read finished from file
            if (finished)
            {
                return;
            }

            // read index from file, if not exists then set it to 0

            index = OneTimeImport(index, len, true);
            if (index == 0)
            {
                finished = true;
            }
            // write index and finished to file
            return;
        }

        static int OneTimeImport(int start, int len, bool waitForIndexing)
        {
            var counter = start < 0 ? 0 : start;

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"D:\PATH\DATA.TXT", Encoding.UTF8))
            using (var session = Store.OpenSession())
            {
                session.Advanced.MaxNumberOfRequestsPerSession = int.MaxValue - 1;

                if (len < 0) len = 16;

                IEnumerable<string> lines = null;
                if (start < 0) { lines = reader.Lines(); }
                else { lines = reader.Lines().Skip(start).Take(len); }

                foreach (var line in lines)
                {
                    var parts = line.Split(new string[] { "|" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                    var lm = new Area();

                    lm.Description = parts[5];
                    var poly = string.Empty;
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(parts[8]))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            var list = new List<Coordinate>();
                            var pairs = parts[8].Split(';');

                            foreach (var p in pairs)
                            {
                                var coor = p.Split(',');

                                var lon = coor[0].ToDouble();
                                var lat = coor[1].ToDouble();
                                list.Add(new Coordinate(lon, lat));
                            }

                            if (list.Count > 0)
                            {
                                list.Add(list[0]);

                                var ring = new LinearRing(list.ToArray());
                                poly = new Polygon(ring).ToString();
                            }
                        }
                        catch { } // some logging
                    }
                    lm.Polygon = poly;

                    session.Store(lm);

                    counter++;
                    if (counter % len == 0)
                    {
                        session.SaveChanges();
                        if (waitForIndexing) while (Store.DatabaseCommands.GetStatistics().StaleIndexes.Length > 0) Thread.Sleep(10);
                    }

                    Trace.WriteLine(counter);
                }

                session.SaveChanges();
                if (waitForIndexing) while (Store.DatabaseCommands.GetStatistics().StaleIndexes.Length > 0) Thread.Sleep(500);
            }

            return counter;
        }

        static void Initialization()
        {
            Store = new DocumentStore { ConnectionStringName = "LoxConnectionString" };
            Store.Initialize();
        }

        static void InitializeIndexes()
        {
            IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(typeof(Program).Assembly, Store);
        }

        public static IEnumerable<string> Lines(this StreamReader reader)
        {
            string line = null;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) yield return line;
        }

        public static double ToDouble(this string s)
        {
            double d = 0;
            double.TryParse(s, out d);
            return d;
        }

        public static DocumentStore Store { get; private set; }
    }

    public class Area
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Polygon { get; set; }
    }

    public class AreaIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Area>
    {
        public AreaIndex()
        {
            Map = docs => from doc in docs
                          select new
                          {
                              doc.Description,
                              _ = SpatialGenerate("AreaPolygon", doc.Polygon)
                          };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out if you ran into a known bug:
http://ayende.com/blog/160450/ravendb-memory-issue-if-i-told-you-once-i-told-you-a-million-times

Comment: Thanks @Desty I have posted this on RavenDB mailing list too. And I'll keep these too synced when I got new results.

Comment: Do you have any answer for your question now?

Comment: @SandRock No, we gave up on RavenDB and gone with PostGIS; since I re-implemented those parts in Go - left .NET for the project; plus some other NoSQLs, boltdb and Cassandra.